# reboot on both resume on boot and wake from hibernation

Tags: grub2, virtualbox, suspend, bios, pm-utils

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, when resuming by clicking on power button/ keyboard button/ opening the lid the laptop will restart, this happens on both linux and windows 10.
One of the speculation that I have strong feelings for is that virtual box has messed with my kernel with its kernel modules (when I was installing it it forwarded me to disable the safe boot option a password was asked to be set in your Ubuntu, when it then restarted the bios openend a password screeen but I couldn't write the password so I had to manually reboot and close the safe boot ) although this was patched on a previous version. pm-hibernate can't resume too. 
suspend command hangs on bash.
adding to the  grub script acpi_sleep=nonvs does nothing.
same with disabling vbox kernel modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that since the suspend to ram and suspend to disk didn't work on both ubuntu and windows 10, it can't be a kernel problem and must be a bios problem (turned out virtualbox aiding tool to disable secure on EFI bios boot messed up with it) I flashed my BIOS to latest update and voila! everything back to normal except that I had reinstall virtualbox-dkms package.